# Django orm, transform object name

Tags: python, django, orm

I can not figure out how to convert the name of the object on the fly

```
LANGUAGES = [ 'en','af', 'ar','az', 'bg','be','bn','bs',]

for i  in LANGUAGES:
    r = myCity.objects.get(id=tet.id)
    r.myCity_base_  (+i)  =(str(z.name))
    r.save
```

You should get something like this
object type standard django orm

```
r.myCity_base_en
r.myCity_base_af
r.myCity_base_az
r.myCity_base_bg
```

thank you for your help

use module
django-modeltranslation

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you aim to achieve. Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: Added information in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with [**`setattr(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) for this:

```
for i  in LANGUAGES:
    r = myCity.objects.get(id=tet.id)
    setattr(r, f'myCity_base_{i}', str(z.name))
    r.save()
```

`setattr(x, 'y', z)` is equivalent to `x.y = z`.

but it is unclear to me where the `z` and `tet` originate from.